# mysql selecting data

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables, `products` and  `product_tags`.

**products table;**

```
product_id int
name varchar
description text
price decimal(12,2)
status enum
sale int
hit int
date_add datatime
date_update datetime
```

**product_tags table;**

```
tag_id int
product_id int
tag varchar
```

where the `product_tags` table has a one to many relation with `products`, for example:

```
tag_id | product_id | tag
1       1             tag1
2       1             tag2
3       1             tag3
```

I want to pull data from a single query. (product and product tags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM products p
 INNER JOIN product_tags pt
    ON (p.product_id = pt.product_id)
```

If you want to fetch all the products regardless of whether they have a tag or not, then use an OUTER JOIN.

```
SELECT *
  FROM products p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN product_tags pt
    ON (p.product_id = pt.product_id)
```

If you are trying to combine all of the tags for each product into a single comma-separated list then something like this might work in mysql:

```
SELECT p.product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(pt.tag SEPARATOR ',')
  FROM products p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN product_tags pt
    ON (p.product_id = pt.product_id)
 GROUP BY p.product_id;
```

For further documentation of GROUP_CONCAT, see the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: tom thank for your answer. But I tried this.

this query retruns more rows. if product has there tags. this query returns three rows.

Comment: yes, if you are selecting data for products AND tags you will get a row for each combination of product and tag. If a product has 3 tags then there will be three rows for that product, one for each tag.

What exactly do you want? Do you want one row for each product with a single column containing a concatenation of all its tags? That sounds a little strange.

Comment: yes i want only result with tags. I think this is not possible. I need to do two separate queries for this is.

like this;

$query_product_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where product_id = '1'");

$query_product_tags_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_tags WHERE product_id = '1'");

this is best way ?

Comment: It is possible in mysql. I've edited my answer to include a solution.